# If a linear combination of variables is normally distributed, then the individual variables are also normally distributed

Tags: probability

As far as I know this is a 'known' fact on Probability. In fact, it completely characterizes the normal distribution. No other distribution has this property.

My question is, do you happen to have a reference for this fact AND a reference for the proof of this fact. I can't find any.

Comment: You need them to be independant, as otherwise I could take a normal random variable $X$ and write it as the sum of $XI(X>0)$ and $XI(X\le 0)$, neither of which are normal. If you assum they are independant, this is known as Cramer's theorem on normal random variables.

Answer (score 1):

The fact:
"*The distribution of a $p$-dimensional random variable $\mathbf{U}$ is completely
determined by the one-dimensional distributions of linear functions $\mathbf{T'U}$, for
every fixed real vector $\mathbf{T}$*", is a result due to Cramer and Wold, and its proof
have the aid of characteristic function. Pls refer to C. R. Rao, *Linear Statistical Inference and its Applications*, 2nd Ed.  John Wiley & Sons, Inc.(2002).  p.517.

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct page? I can't find what you are saying in that book.

Comment: Sorry, in page 517. I correct it. Thank you.